# Suggestions about artificial intelligence project

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have a 1.5 month long internship in this summer, and I will work on artificial intelligence. However, I have never worked on A.I, so this will be first. I should do a list which include some projects or problems about A.I ,and we choose one of them with my advisor, then I will work on this in summer internship. I am doing some researches, but any idea will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is about a specific kind of question (see [What can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the details) and in particular, focuses on specific questions that have a "correct" answer. Your question is interesting, but probably too broad and subjective for this site. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need to be more specific.  There are two general types of AI: those that use machine learning and those that don't.  I assume you want to know about some easy-to-learn machine learning projects, so here:

1. Tic-Tac-Toe
2. Hill Climbing
3. Connect Four

Any low-state game with one way to win is a good beginners project.  Avoid things like Checkers or Chess for the amount of state that needs to be processed makes the AI harder to follow and analyze.  Avoid games like Hearts because multiple win conditions (low score, shoot the moon) make for more confusing algorithms.

I hope this helped.